# Placing two nodes next to each other

Tags: tikz-pgf

My preamble is this:

```
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}                                          
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,positioning}                  
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
```

Currently I am using this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.5cm,
thick,main node/.style={square,fill=blue!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,nodes={rectangle,draw}, row sep=0.5em,
    minimum size=2em, column sep=0em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
    { 80 & \cdots & 166 & \quad & 195 & \cdots & 230 \\ };
    \path[->,font=\scriptsize]
    (m-1-1) edge[bend right=80] node[auto] {} (m-1-5)
    (m-1-1) edge[bend right=80] node[auto] {} (m-1-6)
    (m-1-2) edge[bend right=80] node[auto] {} (m-1-5)
    (m-1-2) edge[bend right=80] node[auto] {} (m-1-7)
    (m-1-3) edge[bend right=80] node[auto] {} (m-1-7)
    (m-1-3) edge[bend right=80] node[auto] {} (m-1-5);

    \node[fill=white,minimum size=2.1em] at (-0.025,0) {};

    \path[->,font=\scriptsize]
    (m-1-5) edge[bend right=80] node[auto] {} (m-1-3)
    (m-1-5) edge[bend right=80] node[auto] {} (m-1-2)
    (m-1-6) edge[bend right=80] node[auto] {} (m-1-1)
    (m-1-6) edge[bend right=80] node[auto] {} (m-1-2)
    (m-1-7) edge[bend right=80] node[auto] {} (m-1-3)
    (m-1-7) edge[bend right=80] node[auto] {} (m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

To create:
[image]

First off, this is very tedious and I am wondering if there is a better way to create such an image in TeX. In particular, creating the gap in the rectangles required me to put a white square node overtop of an empty node by just guessing at the coordinates. I feel there must be a better way. Also, how would I make one of these nodes filled in yellow? They only way I could figure out how to do that is by overwriting the node with a yellow square node and again guessing at where the coordinates are until it seemed right. Please tell me there is a better way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: `{ 80 & \cdots & 166 & |[draw=none]| \quad & 195 & \cdots & 230 \\ }`? For the edges I’d use `\path[bend right=80]` and then two foreach loops.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks! |[draw=none]| worked wonders. Any ideas on how to fill a specific node yellow?

Comment: Well, just the same: `|[fill=yellow]|` at the start of a cell? You can also do stuff like `row 1 column 5/.style={nodes={fill=yellow}}` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way without `\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,positioning}`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth,shorten >=1pt,every node/.style={thick,rectangle,draw,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm}]
        \foreach [count=\i] \content/\fill in {80/yellow, \dots/none, 166/blue}
            \node[fill=\fill] at (\i,0) (\i) {\content};
        \foreach [count=\i from 5] \content/\fill in {195/none, \dots/red, 230/green}
            \node[fill=\fill] at (\i,0) (\i) {\content};
        \foreach \first/\second in {1/5,1/6,2/5,2/7,3/7,3/5,5/3,5/2,6/1,6/2,7/3,7/2}
            \draw[->,thick] (\first) edge[bend right=80] (\second);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]